# Sinatra view and restapi

Tags: rest, sinatra, erb

i'm new here but not a newbie in ruby.

I've a litte question about sinatra.
If i want to use the rest api functionality to generate data from a source (like mysql). How do i decide to use a rest response (only values in json or something other) or an view (html.erb) ?

**routes.rb**

```
get '/api/movies/:id' do
  movie ||= Movie.get(params[:id]) || halt(404)
  format_response(movie, request.accept)
end
```

**response_format.rb**

```
def format_response(data, accept)
  accept.each do |type|
    return data.to_xml  if type.downcase.eql? 'text/xml'
    return data.to_json if type.downcase.eql? 'application/json'
    return data.to_yaml if type.downcase.eql? 'text/x-yaml'
    return data.to_csv  if type.downcase.eql? 'text/csv'
    return data.to_json
  end
end
```

something like: (decide in routes)

```
get '/api/movies/:id' do
  movie ||= Movie.get(params[:id]) || halt(404)
  request.user_agent =~ /Mozilla/ ? format_response(movie, request.accept) : erb :view_movie
end
```

or like: (decide in helper)

```
def format_response(data, accept)
  accept.each do |type|
    return data.to_xml  if type.downcase.eql? 'text/xml'
    return data.to_json if type.downcase.eql? 'application/json'
    return data.to_yaml if type.downcase.eql? 'text/x-yaml'
    return data.to_csv  if type.downcase.eql? 'text/csv'
    erb :view_movie     if type.downcase.eql? 'text/html'
  end
end
```